# Change flag colour for case object

Tags: datetime, formula-field, image-formula

I have a requirement here. I have to change the color of a case flag from yellow to red depending upon certain criteria. the criteria is Whenever an Email-to-case is created and Case owner is in "Unassigned Queue" ( Case owner is mapped with a queue ). If the case is in Unassigned queue , then i should display a yellow flag. if the case remains in Unassigned queue for more than 15 minutes, then i should display a red flag. 
Now, I have created a custom datetime field (say UnassignedDate__c), so whenever Case Owner is moved to Unassigned Queue, then UnassignedDate__c gets populated. I would make the flag to yellow. But i want to check for the red flag condition here. Here, i have to check for EST time for 15 minutes. I tried something like this

> IF( NOT (ISBLANK(UnassignedDate__c)) , IMAGE('myyellowimage'),  IF( VALUE(ROUND(MOD( ((NOW()-0.1667)-UnassignedDate__c)*1440,60),0)) >= 15, IMAGE('myRedImage'), ''))

I'm not sure what am missing here. I'm unable to get red image. but i'm getting only yellow image.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that will be checked is whether or not UnassignedDate__c is blank. If it isn't, then the Yellow image will be shown (always) and the rest of the if-statement will be ignored.

Presuming the other part of your formula is correct, the solution would be to first check for the red flag (which is a 'tighter' constraint) and if that is not applicable, check for the yellow flag.

```
IF( 
    VALUE(ROUND(MOD( ((NOW()-0.1667)-UnassignedDate__c)*1440,60),0)) >= 15
    , 
    IMAGE('myRedImage')
    , 
    IF( 
        NOT (ISBLANK(UnassignedDate__c))
        , 
        IMAGE('myyellowimage')
        ,
        ''
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with the solution for what i need. This may be helpful for you in one way or the other.

> `IF(
>   AND(
>   NOT(ISBLANK(RM_Unassigned_Date__c)),
>   (FLOOR(( DateNow__c - RM_Unassigned_Date__c)*24)) +
>   ROUND((((
>   ((DateNow__c - RM_Unassigned_Date__c)*24)-
>   FLOOR((DateNow__c - RM_Unassigned_Date__c)*24))
>   *60)/100),2) >= 0.15
>   ),
>   IMAGE("/resource/RedFlag","Red",20,20),
>   IF(
>   AND(
>   NOT(ISBLANK(RM_Unassigned_Date__c)),
>   (FLOOR(( DateNow__c - RM_Unassigned_Date__c)*24)) +
>   ROUND((((
>   ((DateNow__c - RM_Unassigned_Date__c)*24)-
>   FLOOR((DateNow__c - RM_Unassigned_Date__c)*24))
>   *60)/100),2) < 0.15
>   ),
>   IMAGE("/resource/YellowFlag","Yellow",20,20),null
>   )
>   )`

This will give you the flag change depending upon the minutes and hours between 2 datetime fields. DateNow__c contains the value for the NOW() with respect to ur local time zones